# How to increase value by a certain number?

Tags: sqlite

How to increase a value in a table by a certain number without reading last value and afterwards updating it?

| product | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| iLamp | 50 |

I want to increase (or decrease) quantity by x. I am first reading last value (50), increasing or decreasing it, and writing it back. Is there a direct way?

Answer (score 280, accepted):

**Example 1** (for all rows):

```
UPDATE product SET price = price + 50
```

**Example 2** (for a specific row):

```
UPDATE product SET price = price + 50 WHERE id = 1
```

**Example 3** (for specific rows):

```
UPDATE product SET price = price + 50 WHERE id IN [1, 2, 3]
```

**Example 4** (generic):

```
UPDATE {table} SET {column} = {column} + {value} WHERE {condition}
```

Where:

- `{table}` - table name
- `{column}` - column name
- `{value}` - a number by which column's value should be increased or decreased
- `{condition}` - some condition if any

Comment: FROM is an SQLite keyword? The docs don't seem to indicate it. http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Comment: @user3358205: Like the man says... `UPDATE table SET col = col + 1 WHERE first_column = ?`

Comment: To increment on [a list of criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041476/combining-a-large-number-of-conditions-in-sqlite-where-clause), do something like `UPDATE Products SET Price = Price + 50 WHERE [ProductID] IN [1,3,56,78,44,23,8989,23]`

Comment: @Konstantin is this possible to increment all row value of an column incrementally ? Say if existing rows are "R, S, T" then it should be 'R1, S2, T3'. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @CoDe you would use `row_number() over(ORDER BY id)`  for that