# Android SQLite incrementing a column value

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to create a score database that increments the players 'score' by one when they win by calling updateScore(). The primary key and player number are identical (I may need to restructure the DB at some point) and the final column is 'score'.

Below is the code that initially sets the score (this works), the method that gets the score (also works fine) and the method that updates the score, incrementing the relevant players score by 1. This is the part the doesn't work, is there something I should be doing differently here? Thanks.

```
     /** Add a record to the database of two player scores
     * @param playerId
     * @param playerScore
     **/
    public void addScore (int playerId, int playerScore) {

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(ID, playerId);
        values.put(PLAYERNUM, playerId);
        values.put(SCORE, playerScore);

        database.insert(TABLE_2PSCORES, null, values);

        database.close();

    }


    // Get the score 
    public int getScore (int playerId) { 
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_2PSCORES, COLUMNS, " player = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(playerId) }, null, null, null, null); //null = groupby, having, orderby, limit

        if (cursor !=null) { cursor.moveToFirst(); }

        int output = cursor.getInt(2);

        return output;
    }


    // Increment score by 1
    public void updateScore (int playerId) {

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        int playerScore = getScore(playerId);
        int playerScoreInc = playerScore ++;

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("score", playerScoreInc);

        database.update(TABLE_2PSCORES, values, PLAYERNUM+" = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(playerId)} );

        database.close();

    }
```

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9798473/sqlite-in-android-how-to-update-a-specific-row

Comment: Look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744289/sqlite-increase-value-by-a-certain-number

Comment: close cursors after use, better programming practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
int playerScoreInc = playerScore ++;
```

to

```
int playerScoreInc = ++ playerScore;
```

Answer (score 10):

```
int playerScoreInc = playerScore ++;
```

This assigns `playerScore` to `playerScoreInc` and only after that increments `playerScore`. To first increment and then assign, change to `++playerScore`.

However, you can do it all in SQL, no need to fetch score, increment it in code and then update the database table separately:

```
database.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_2PSCORES + " SET " + SCORE + "=" + SCORE + "+1" + " WHERE " + PLAYERNUM + "=?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(playerId) } );
```

Answer (score 5):

The other answers solve the original question, but the syntax makes it hard to understand. This is a more general answer for future viewers.

## How to increment a SQLite column value

**SQLite**

The general SQLite syntax is

```
UPDATE {Table} SET {Column} = {Column} + {Value} WHERE {Condition}
```

An example of this is

```
UPDATE Products SET Price = Price + 1 WHERE ProductID = 50
```

*(Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/744290/3681880))*

**Android**

Now that the general syntax is clear, let me translate that into Android syntax.

```
private static final String PRODUCTS_TABLE = "Products";
private static final String ID = "ProductID";
private static final String PRICE = "Price";

String valueToIncrementBy = "1";
String productId = "50";
String[] bindingArgs = new String[]{ valueToIncrementBy, productId };

SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
db.execSQL("UPDATE " + PRODUCTS_TABLE +
        " SET " + PRICE + " = " + PRICE + " + ?" +
        " WHERE " + ID + " = ?",
        bindingArgs);
db.close();
```

**TODO**

This answer should be updated to use [`update`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)) rather than [`execSQL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)). See comment below.

Comment: The android docs says: Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. The issue is that execSql(..) does not return the number of affected rows. Any other solution?

Comment: @Sunnyday, you're right. Good catch. It looks like I should be using [`update`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update(java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) instead.

Comment: But using update means you have to query the current score from the table before updating the same table. It would have been much easier to pass some DML to the `update` method. I still use the `execSql` for that reason.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work

```
 // Increment score by 1
    public void updateScore (int playerId) {

        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

        int playerScore = getScore(playerId);
        int playerScoreInc = ++ playerScore;

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("score", playerScoreInc);

        database.update(TABLE_2PSCORES, values, PLAYERNUM+" = ?", new String[] {String.valueOf(playerId)} );

        database.close();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. A few answers reference the ++playerscore over playerscore++, and this has fixed my problem. Thanks again!

Comment: the ++var mean increment before the assignment and the val++ means increment after that assignment. Thats why it wasn't updating for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging? Try debugging this line:

```
int playerScoreInc = playerScore ++;
```

The playerScoreInc doesn't increment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had tired debugging but didn't get anything useful. I now have the answer.

Comment: If you debugged this code line I copied, you would have been the value didn't increment. Then the you would have found the answer yourself easily :)