# SQLite increment through recycle view

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have an sqlite with columns name, credits,absent. I want to increment the value of absent with a button click from the recycle view where it displays all sqlite data. Can you help?
Thanks in advance.

my SqliteHelper-

```
public class Myhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME="mydatabase.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="mytable";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID="_id";
    public static final String COL_1="NAME";
    public static  final String COL_2="CREDIT";
    public  static final String COL_3="BUNKS";
    public static final String[] COLUMNS ={COLUMN_ID,COL_1,COL_2,COL_3};
    Context con;

    public Myhelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        con = context;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable= "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_ID +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + " NAME TEXT, CREDIT TEXT, BUNKS INTEGER )";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
        Toast.makeText(con,"table created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }
    public boolean insertData(String x,String y,int z){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_1, String.valueOf(x));
        contentValues.put(COL_2,String.valueOf(y));
       contentValues.put(COL_3,z);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<String> queryXdata(){
        ArrayList<String> xnewdata= new ArrayList<String>();
        String query = "SELECT "+ COL_1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(query,null);
        for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
            xnewdata.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_1)));
        }
        cursor.close();
        return xnewdata;

    }
    public ArrayList<Integer> queryYdata(){
        ArrayList<Integer> ynewdata= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String query = "SELECT "+ COL_3+ " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(query,null);
        for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
            ynewdata.add(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_3)));
        }
        cursor.close();
        return ynewdata;

    }
    public  ArrayList<Integer> queryZdata(){
       ArrayList<Integer> znewdata= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String query = "SELECT "+ COL_2+ " FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(query,null);
        for (cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){
            znewdata.add(((cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_2))));
        }
        cursor.close();
        return znewdata;
    }

    public attendence getdetails(long id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query= "SELECT" + COL_2+" FROM " + TABLE_NAME +" WHERE _id=" + id;
        Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery(query,null);
        attendence attendence1= new attendence();
        if (cursor.getCount()>0){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            attendence1.setSubname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_1)));
            attendence1.setCredit(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_2)));
            attendence1.setBunks(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_3)));
        }
        return attendence1;
    }

    public void delete(long id,Context context){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE _id='"+id+"'");
        Toast.makeText(context,"delted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public List<attendence> list(String  filter){
        String query;
        if (filter.equals("")){
            query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME ;

        }
        else {
            query= " SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME ;

        }
        List<attendence> linkedlist = new LinkedList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        attendence attendence;
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                attendence = new attendence();
                attendence.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)));
                attendence.setSubname(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_1)));
                attendence.setCredit(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_2)));
                attendence.setBunks(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_3)));
                linkedlist.add(attendence);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return linkedlist;
    }


    public int getbunk(int id){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS,"_id=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null,null );
        if (cursor!=null){cursor.moveToFirst();}
       int output = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_3));
        cursor.close();
        return output;

    }
    public void updatebunk(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        int bunk = getbunk(id);
        int bunkinc= ++bunk;
        ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_3,bunkinc);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,COLUMN_ID+" =?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
        db.close();
    }

}
```

myRecycleViewAdapter

```
public class attendence_recycleadapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<attendence_recycleadapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<attendence> mattendence_list;
    private Context mcontext;
    public RecyclerView mrecycleview;
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public attendence_recycleadapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendence_recycleview_card,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull attendence_recycleadapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final attendence attendence= mattendence_list.get(position);

        holder.subname.setText("Name: " + attendence.getSubname());
        holder.subcredit.setText("CREDIT: " + attendence.getCredit());
        holder.bunks.setText("BUNKS: " + attendence.getBunks());
        holder.deletesub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Myhelper myhelper = new Myhelper(mcontext);
               myhelper.delete(attendence.getId(),mcontext);
              // mattendence_list.remove(position);
              // mrecycleview.removeViewAt(position);
               notifyItemRemoved(position);
               notifyItemRangeChanged(position,mattendence_list.size());
               notifyDataSetChanged();
                delete(position);
            }
        });
        holder.addbunk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Myhelper myhelper = new Myhelper(mcontext);
              myhelper.updatebunk(position);
              notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mattendence_list.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView subname;
        public TextView subcredit;
        public TextView bunks;
        public View layout;
        public Button addbunk;

        public Button deletesub;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            layout=itemView;
            subname=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.attendernce_subname);
            subcredit=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.attendernce_credit);
            bunks=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.attendernce_bunks);

            addbunk = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.attendence_addbunk);
            deletesub = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.attendence_deletesub);

        }
    }
    public void add(int position,attendence attendence2){
        mattendence_list.add(position,attendence2);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }
    public  void delete(int position){
        mattendence_list.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
    public attendence_recycleadapter(List<attendence> mydataset, Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView){
        mattendence_list =  mydataset;
        mcontext = context;
        mrecycleview= recyclerView;
    }

}
```

i am getting errror in getBunk() when i click on addbunk button. there is a problem in getbunk() as the cursor is not able to find any value.

error message:android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Comment: Show us some code you tried.

Comment: Check this answer for how to increment values in SQLite. You can `execSQL` it, using your own table and field names. https://stackoverflow.com/a/744290/37020

Comment: Will you tell what's wrong with the code? Does it throw an exception? or it does not write the desired value to the db?

Comment: I have shown the code. please see into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had several mistakes in your code.  
I rewrote the 2 methods.   
Now `getbunk` returns `-1` if the `id` is not found.   
I hope I made no typos.   
Try the below code, and if you need explanation, ask:

```
public int getbunk(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + COL_3 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COLUMN_ID + " = " + String.valueOf(id), null);
    int output = -1;

    if (cursor != null){
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            output = cursor.getInt(0);
        }

        cursor.close();
    }

    db.close();

    return output;
}

public void updatebunk(int id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    int bunk = getbunk(id);

    if (bunk < 0) {
        Log.i("Error:", "Id=" + id + " not found!");
        return;
    }

    int bunkinc = ++bunk;

    ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_3, bunkinc);
    db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues,COLUMN_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: @sagarshetty If it helped you accept it as the right answer

Comment: Can you tell how to update this in my recycle view at the same time. I have to relaunch the activity for it to show the increment.

Comment: @sagarshetty In your activity class you have a list and this list is attached to the recyclerview adapter. Use the id to find the row in the list and change what you want. After that call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();`

Comment: I am new to this. Can you help me out my showing some code? . I am not sure how I can do this.  I  only implement recycle view adaptor in the activity.

Comment: Exactly, this list is in your activity. I suggest you start a new question about what you want to do, including all the relevant code of your activity class, the adapter and the db

Comment: Please look into this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51610547/how-can-i-change-the-contents-of-recycleview-at-the-same-time-change-the-data-in