# Android Studio (SQLite Database), I am gonna to add a LineNo to a table and how can I make it will auto increment by 1?

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

I am gonna to add a LineNo to a table and how can I make it will auto increment by 1?
LineNo is no the primary key so how I make it will will auto increment by 1?

This is what I tried, but no working:
String query_edit  = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME_INV_DTL + " SET " + COL15_INV_DTL + "= +1 ";
db.execSQL(query_edit);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite - increase value by a certain number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744289/sqlite-increase-value-by-a-certain-number)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String query_edit = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME_INV_DTL + " SET " + COL15_INV_DTL + "=" + COL15_INV_DTL + " +1 "; 
db.execSQL(query_edit);
```